# Javascript: Resize event being fired twice on each event

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have a "Graphics" object in JS that i'm using as a container for the canvas element.

The graphics objects just takes in a canvas and sets it's width, height, etc.

I have this function being called on the resize event:

```
Graphics.prototype.resize = function(){

   this.canvas.width = (this.canvas.width > window.innerWidth) 
                         ? window.innerWidth : someDefaultVar;

   //And same for width...

  alert(this.canvas.width); //Alert for test purposes
};
```

Assuming the canvas.width < window.innerWidth and window.innerWidth = 205 this is the alert output for each resize:

205

Original Width

I'm puzzled as to why it's being called twice, thus resulting in the canvas not resizing.

In my animation loop I'm using the object as so:

```
window.addEventListener("load",Main,false); //Added from comment response, 
                                            //load eventlistener

function Main(){
   var canvas = new Graphics(width, height ..); //Object containing the canvas

   window.addEventListener("resize", OnResize,false); //Add the event listener
                                                       // for resize

   function OnResize(){

      canvas.resize(); //Call the function named above
   }

   function AnimLoop(){

       canvas.draw();
       requestAnimationFrame(AnimLoop);
   }

   AnimLoop(); //Call AnimLoop entering starting the animation
}
```

Can anyone spot the problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: How many times does "Main" get called?  The `addEventListener` function does in fact **add** an event listener, without affecting previously-added listeners.

Comment: Once, sorry forgot to add the entry point for main. Editing now.

Comment: Well, I'd still drop a `console.log()` in there to be sure.

Comment: I can't see how it would get called more than once with that logic? But cheers, just logged to confirm it doesn't.

Comment: Yes I agree but I've found lots of bugs in code I knew was OK :) Well, another thing to note is that browsers fire the "resize" event very frequently while you've got the mouse button down on the window handle. Are you sure it's being called 4 times on the *same* "resize" event?

Comment: Yeah sorry my response was on the blunt side lol. Yeah sorry it's being fired twice each resize event, naturally resulting in the canvas resizing then reverting to the original dimensions. Late night coding for you lol.

Comment: Might be an issue with the browser after some research. Damn web programming.

Comment: Is it perhaps firing twice in response to an initial change in height? Perhaps you could try adding variables to store the last known width and height and only execute your resize logic if one of them have changed?

Comment: Resize will always fire 1+ times because resizing takes a while to complete.  To receive the resize event only once you need a "debouncer" like throttledresize.js:  https://github.com/louisremi/jquery-smartresize

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The resize event can be thrown several times for various reasons. What you can do is to implement a timer so that your resize is triggered only when the events aren't thrown in a bunch.

For example:

```
function Main(){
   var canvas = new Graphics(width, height ..);

   /// add a var in main to hold the timer request id    
   var resizeTimer;

   window.addEventListener("resize", OnResize,false);

   function OnResize(){

      /// reset timeout every time resize is triggered
      /// no need to check the value
      clearTimeout(resizeTimer);

      /// setup timer so that when the delay between events
      /// are higher than 200 ms call resize canvas..
      resizeTimer = setTimout(canvas.resize, 200);
   }

   ...    
}
```

What happens here is when resize events are triggering the callback it will wait until there has elapsed 200ms (experiment with this value, this is just some initial value) before it actually calls the canvas resize. This helps reduce the load and update of canvas and handles the events faster.

Hope this helps.