# Can I center canvas image

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm drawing a large canvas image as a background, the image is larger that the window size. I'm wondering if theres a way for me to center the image to fit on full screen. If so, how? this is what I'm doing:

```
        var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
            context = canvas.getContext('2d');

        window.addEventListener('resize', resizeCanvas, false);

        function resizeCanvas() {
            canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
            canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

            drawStuff(); 
        }

        resizeCanvas();

        function drawStuff() {
            var imageObj = new Image();

            imageObj.onload = function() {
                context.drawImage(imageObj, 69, 50);
            };

            imageObj.src = '/resources/img/bg.png';
        }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an optional way of centering an image to canvas not using transform (also see note below):

```
imageObj.onload = function() {

    var x = (canvas.width  - this.width ) * 0.5,   // this = image loaded
        y = (canvas.height - this.height) * 0.5;

    ctx.drawImage(this, x, y);
};
```

Since the image is larger than the canvas x and y will be negative in this case, which is perfectly fine. If the image was smaller it would work just as fine too. If you do the drawing outside the load handler you would of course need to use `imageObj` instead of `this`.

**NOTE:** The way you have set up your resize handler is not the best way to handle image repositioning - you should only load the image once, then reuse that object. As resizing typically creates a number of events it would trigger an equal number of image reloads.

For this to work properly you could do something like this instead:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
    context = canvas.getContext('2d'),

    imageObj = new Image();  // declare globally

imageObj.onload = function() {

    // now set up handler when image is actually loaded
    // - else drawImage will fail (width, height is not available and no data)
    window.addEventListener('resize', resizeCanvas, false);

    // initial call to draw image first time
    resizeCanvas();  
};

imageObj.src = '/resources/img/bg.png';

function resizeCanvas() {
    canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

    drawStuff(); 
}

function drawStuff() {
    var x = (canvas.width  - imageObj.width ) * 0.5,
        y = (canvas.height - imageObj.height) * 0.5;

    ctx.drawImage(imageObj, x, y);
}
```

It's not perfect as the resize event queue will still be large and may lag - there are solutions for this too, for example [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20961916/javascript-resize-event-being-fired-twice-on-each-event/20964115#20964115) (with minor modifications).

Answer (score 2):

Here's how to center the image on the canvas.  Any vertical or horizontal overflow will be off-canvas:

```
imageObj.onload = function() {
    ctx.translate(canvas.width/2,canvas.height/2);
    ctx.drawImage(imageObj,-imageObj.width/2,-imageObj.height/2);
    ctx.translate(-canvas.width/2,-canvas.height/2);
};
```

Good luck with your project!

Answer (score 0):

If you are adding image after uploading then you can use this, it works for me :)
var image_center_width = (canvas.width - img.width) / 2;
                            var image_center_height = (canvas.height - img.height) / 2;

```
                        img.set({
                                left : image_center_width,
                                top : image_center_height,
                            });
                    canvas.add(img)
```